# Use the generalization of Euler's criterion to determine if 16 is a cubic residue modulo 31...

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Use the generalization of Euler's criterion to determine if $16$ is a cubic residue modulo $31$.

So far I have:

$p = 31$, $m = 3$,

$d = (p-1, m) = (30,3) = 3$

if $16^{30/3}= 16^{10}= 1 \pmod{31}$

I am a bit unsure if my current steps are correct and how to simplify $16^{10}$ to check if it is in fact $1 \pmod{31}$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your steps are correct. To finish,
note that $2^5\equiv 1\pmod{31}$, so $16^5=(2^5)^4\equiv 1\pmod{31}$, and therefore $16^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{31}$.

*Remark:* Even if we do not notice the simple way of doing the computation in one's head, calculating the remainder when $16^{10}$ is divided by $31$ is not difficult.